# Javascript - Append row -dependent drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a help to fix my dependent drop down list cloning problem. i have these three fields, `1.country_name,2.store_model,3.location_list`, and on selecting country_name the store_model will populate and on selecting store_model the location lists will populate. this is working fine, but when i try to clone and append a row, the appended dropdown is not working properly. in the appended dropdown, the values are displaying based on the original dropdown selection.

this is my PHP page

```
        <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
    <form action="functions.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    class="form-horizontal form_emp" id="form_sample_3" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-body">
    <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="id">
    <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $sp_id;?>" name="sp_id">
    <input type="hidden"  class="form-control tot_in" value="0" name="total_in">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-scrollable">
    <table class="table table-bordered edit-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>                                                                    
    <th width="10%"> # </th>
    <th width="20%"> Country </th>
    <th width="20%"> Store Model</th>
    <th width="20%"> Loaction</th>
    <th width="30%"> Update Comments </th>                                  
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="items-row">
    <?php
    if(empty($userdata)):
    ?>                                                                  
    <tr class="item-row">                                                   
    <td>

    <a title="Remove row" href="javascript:;" class="dodelete delete btn red btn-outline">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>

    <td class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control country_name" name="country_name[]">
    <?php $q=mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`country_name` FROM `db_country` WHERE  id in (select distinct country_id from db_locations where location_id in (select location_id from db_sp where sp_id=$sp_id)) ");
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<option ".(in_array($res['id'],$country_name)?"selected":"")." value='".$res['id']."'>".$res['country_name']."</option>"; 
    }?>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control store_model" name="store_model[]">
    <?php
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`store_model` FROM `db_store_model` WHERE  id in (select distinct store_model_id from db_locations where location_id in (select location_id from db_sp where sp_id=$sp_id)) ");
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<option ".(in_array($res['id'],$store_model)?"selected":"")." value='".$res['id']."'>".$res['store_model']."</option>";   
    }?>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control location_list" name="location_list[]">
    <?php
    if(!empty($id)){
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT `location_id`,`location_name` FROM `db_locations` WHERE  location_id in (select location_id from db_sp where sp_id=$sp_id)");
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<option ".(in_array($res['location_id'],$location_list)?"selected":"")." value='".$res['location_id']."'>".$res['location_name']."</option>"; 
    }}?>
    </select>
    <div class="form-control-focus loading"> </div>
    </td>

    <td align="centre" class="form-group form-md-line-input"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comments[]"></td>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    else:
    $count=count($sp_detail);
    for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
    ?>
    <tr class="item-row">

    <a title="Remove row" href="javascript:;" class="dodelete delete btn red btn-outline">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    <td class="form-group form-md-line-input"> 
    <select multiple="multiple"  class="form-control country_name" name="country_name[]">
    <option value="">Select Any</option>
    <?php foreach($country_name as $key=>$cname){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ;?>" <?php echo ($sp_detail[$i]['country_name']==$key?"selected":"");?>><?php echo $cname ;?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>

    </td>
    <td class="form-group form-md-line-input"> 
    <select multiple="multiple"  class="form-control store_model" name="store_model[]">
    <option value="">Select Any</option>
    <?php foreach($store_model as $key=>$smodel){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ;?>" <?php echo ($sp_detail[$i]['store_model']==$key?"selected":"");?>><?php echo $smodel ;?></option>
    <?php }?>
    <div class="form-control-focus loading"> </div>
    </td>

    <td class="form-group form-md-line-input"> 
    <select multiple="multiple"  class="form-control location_list" name="location_list[]">
    <option value="">Select Any</option>
    <?php foreach($location_list as $key=>$loclist){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ;?>" <?php echo ($sp_detail[$i]['location_list']==$key?"selected":"");?>><?php echo $loclist ;?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>
    <div class="form-control-focus loading"> </div>
    </td>
    </tr>



    <?php   
    }
    endif;
    ?>
    </tbody>

    </table>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <a title="Add a row" href="javascript:;" class="addrow btn blue btn-outline">Add a row</a>


    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 invoice-block text-right">
    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="form_control_1">Update Type
    <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="event_status">
    <option value="1">Update</option>
    </select>
    <div class="form-control-focus"> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="update_event" class="btn green">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn default reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <!-- END FORM-->
```

this is my functions.php

```
        if(isset($_POST['action'])&& $_POST['action']=='selectUpdate'){
    $post=$_POST;

$country_id=json_encode($post['country_name']);
$country_ids=join(',',$post['country_name']);
$sp_id=$post['sp_id'];

$store_model_id=json_encode($post['store_model']);
$store_model_ids=join(',',$post['store_model']);

    $q=mysql_query("SELECT `location_id`,`location_name` FROM `db_locations` WHERE country_id in ($country_ids) and store_model_id in ($store_model_ids) and location_id in (select location_id from db_sp where sp_id=$sp_id)order by country_id,store_model_id");
$qno=mysql_num_rows($q);

if($qno>0){
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        echo "<option value='".$res['location_id']."'>".$res['location_name']."</option>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "<option value=''>No Data</option>";
}
    }
```

this is my JavaScript

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(document).on('click','.dodelete',function(){
    if($('.edit-table #items-row').find('tr').length > 1) { $(this).parents('tr').remove(); }
    else{alert('All rows cant be deleted');}

});

var setSelectsEvents = function(rowElement) {
    $(rowElement).on('change', '.country_name,.store_model', function(){
        var store_model=$(rowElement).find('.store_model')[0].value;
        var country_name=$(rowElement).find('.country_name')[0].value;
        var sp_id=<?php echo $sp_id ?>;
        //var store_model=$(this).val();
        $('.loading').html('<img src="layouts/layout/img/loading.gif"/>');
        $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'functions.php',
         data: {
           sp_id:<?php echo $sp_id ?>,store_model:store_model,country_name:country_name, action:"selectUpdate",
         },

         success: function (res) {
            $('.loading').html("");
            $($(rowElement).find('.location_list')[0]).html(res); 
            $('#my_multi_select1').multiSelect();
         }
       });
    });
};
setSelectsEvents('.item-row');

$('.addrow').click(function(){
    var elem = $('#items-row').find('tr:first').clone();
    var appendedRow = $('#items-row').append(elem).children(':last-child');
    setSelectsEvents(appendedRow);
});

$(document).on('click','.reset',function(){
    emptyTable();
});
```

});

$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: 'dateToday',
        //startDate: '+15d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});

im not good at JavaScript, somewhere i am making mistake. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has some event handler like $('select.coutry_name').on('change', ...
But these event handlers are not set cloned rows selects.
So it will work fine selects event handler part and $('.addrow').click change to like following.

```
// **UPDATED JavaScript**

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){      


    $(document).on('click','.dodelete',function(){
        if($('.edit-table #items-row').find('tr').length > 1) { $(this).parents('tr').remove(); }
        else{alert('All rows cant be deleted');}

    });

    var setSelectsEvents = function(rowElement) {
        $(rowElement).on('change', '.country_name,.store_model', function(){
            var store_model=$($(rowElement).find('.store_model')[0]).val();
            var country_name=$($(rowElement).find('.country_name')[0]).val();
            var sp_id=<?php echo $sp_id ?>;
            //var store_model=$(this).val();
            $('.loading').html('<img src="layouts/layout/img/loading.gif"/>');
            var data = {
              sp_id:1,store_model:store_model,country_name:country_name, action:"selectUpdate",
            };
            $('.loading').html('<img src="/images/loading.gif"/>');
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'functions.php',
              data: JSON.stringify(data),
              contentType: 'application/JSON',
              dataType : 'JSON',

              success: function (res) {
                $('.loading').html("");
                $($(rowElement).find('.location_list')[0]).html(res); 
                $('#my_multi_select1').multiSelect();
              }
            });
        });
    };
    setSelectsEvents('.item-row');

    $('.addrow').click(function(){
        var elem = $('#items-row').find('tr:first').clone();
        var appendedRow = $('#items-row').append(elem).children(':last-child');
        setSelectsEvents(appendedRow);
    });

    $(document).on('click','.reset',function(){
        emptyTable();
    });


});

$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: 'dateToday',
        //startDate: '+15d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});



</script>
```

Comment: thank you, i have updated the full Javascript in the question, i have altered it as per your suggestion, i am not able to manage to get it work as expected. please advice.

Comment: I have seen your update. It needs to be modified little more.
I have copied and modified your updated script, and updated my script to that. How about that?

Comment: thank you, i have updated the code, now the location list is not populating after selecting country and store model. please help

Comment: Looking at the browser developer tool, is there any error?

Comment: in the first row select, the country name and store model is working, location list is not displaying after selecting the country name and store model.

Comment: i have updated your latest code, the location list is not populating, i checked in browser console post params, the selected values are showing properly, but in the response i get no values. i am not sure whether the selected values are posted

Comment: Is your post data format JSON? If it is JSON, data property of ajax has to modify to following.

data: JSON.stringify({
               sp_id:<?php echo $sp_id ?>,store_model:store_model,country_name:country_name, action:"selectUpdate",
             })

Comment: sorry for delayed response, yea it was working before the update, the only problem then was while cloning the first row, the cloned row values were populating based on the first row's selection.

Comment: Don't worry. Yeah I forgot the append method returns the original element. I fixed that problem. Please test again.

Comment: i have updated my php page in the question, i also updated the javascript, but it is not working. kindly advice.

Comment: I modified javascript for post data by JSON, and replace the append method to appendTo method. I will write another answer about PHP part.

Answer (score 1):

It is posted data in JSON, has to decode JSON data on PHP.

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])&& $_POST['action']=='selectUpdate'){
    $post=json_decode($_POST, true);

    //$country_id=json_encode($post['country_name']);  //not used
    $country_ids=is_array($post['country_name']) ? join(',',$post['country_name']) : $post['country_name'];
    $sp_id=$post['sp_id'];

    //$store_model_id=json_encode($post['store_model']);  //not used
    $store_model_ids=is_array($post['store_model']) ? join(',',$post['store_model']) : $post['store_model'];

    $q=mysql_query("SELECT `location_id`,`location_name` FROM `db_locations` WHERE country_id in ($country_ids) and store_model_id in ($store_model_ids) and location_id in (select location_id from db_sp where sp_id=$sp_id)order by country_id,store_model_id");
    $qno=mysql_num_rows($q);

    if($qno>0){
        while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
            echo "<option value='".$res['location_id']."'>".$res['location_name']."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option value=''>No Data</option>";
    }
}
```